# PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter causes wrong behaviour

Tags: php, phpexcel

After having created a PHPExcel program, the final step consists of saving the worksheets, to do that, I want to apply these rules so as to generate the file in Excel 2007:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="workbook1.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Instead of getting the Excel2007 file, the ouptut with any kind of browser is something like:

> 07:31:12 Create new PHPExcel object 07:31:12 Set properties 07:31:12
>   Add some data 07:31:12 Rename sheet 07:31:12 Write to Excel2007 format
>   PKæ;È< —![[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷=…å-JÜ²@%í‚Â*Q`ìIcÕ±-{úw{&I ˆE
>   j7±"û½oüg÷œ%”NKë”ü‰Ï¦£by‰]*y„Hª†F¦Üp4SùØH¤ß¸Aªµ\¸ï„òÁa†­ŸŽXñJD£-dÄÙHì­
>   .....

I tried with various browsers but I get the same result. On the other hand, if I save the file with these lines below, it works fine:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007'); 
$objWriter->save('/usr/local/myWorkbooks/workbook1.xlsx');
```

Any idea why it does not work through my browser? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you're streaming the output to php://output then you must not echo anything else to that output stream. 
You're clearly echoing the lines:

```
07:31:12 Create new PHPExcel object 
07:31:12 Set properties 
07:31:12 Add some data 
07:31:12 Rename sheet 
07:31:12 Write to Excel2007 format
```

to output before the Excel file itself

Remove those echo lines

This is standard PHP behavior, and a question that has been answered here thousands of times in the past: echoes go to php://output.... I'm surprised you're not also getting a "headers already sent" error as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no echo in my code, the header of the error message shown in my previous message had nothing to do with the output, sorry for this inconvenience.

Here's the output below, for unknown reason I can't generate the Excel 2007 file from my Browser, any idea why?

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homez.40/foodbank/www/phpexcel/Tests/testyves3.php:9) in /homez.40/foodbank/www/phpexcel/Tests/testyves3.php on line 77

PK-;EA½Ha¹rä[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY „švAa •(0ö¤±êØ–Çý»=“¤„Ô”*Ùd%ï .....

Comment: According to the message you've just added here: "output started at /homez.40/foodbank/www/phpexcel/Tests/testyves3.php:9" means that something is being sent to php://output at line 9 of the testyves3.php script in the /homez.40/foodbank/www/phpexcel/Tests/ directory. Based on the output you're showing in your original question, that "something" is going to be the message "07:31:12 Create new PHPExcel object".

Comment: Remember that anything between ?> and <?php in your script will also be sent to php://output exactly is if you'd echoed it

Comment: Thanks Mark,

Here are the line generating the warning messages:

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Report.xlsx"');
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); I found lots of similar examples using these lines, what's wrong? Thanks Yves

Comment: The output is at line __9__ not at line __77__. You're getting the errors at line 77 (the lines containing the header() statements) but the error is triggered by output at line 9 (the reference in barckets in the error message)... what is in your PHP code between lines 8 and 10?

Comment: Line 9 simply contains this: <?php the beginning of my php code followed by:
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
located in the <head> html and then the rest of the php code is located in the <body> part

Comment: If your opening PHP <?php is at line 9, then everything between lines 1 and line 8 is being sent to php://output

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean the output buffer and turn off buffering using `ob_end_clean()` before saving. Do this instead:

```
    $objWriter =  PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="workbook1.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```